# Use MediaWiki auto-pagination outside of Category pages?

Tags: mediawiki

When I visit:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1938_births

it shows me the first 200 pages in this category with a link to the next 200.

Can I use this magical auto-pagination on my regular pages somehow?

I'm using wikia.com and do not have shell access.

Comment: How do you mean? What is it that you want to paginate? The page contents? In that case there are extensions for that. Or page links?

Comment: I want to paginate any list on a page. Example: I want to create one page with a 1000-item list. I know want MediaWiki to automatically show the first 200 items on the page when people visit it, and allow them to click to see the next 200 items and so on.

Comment: If you want lists of a certain kind to be automatically paginated I believe you will have to create your own extension for that (or use MediaWiki:Common.js). If you can add headers where the pagination should occur, try https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Header_Tabs. If Semantic MediaWiki is an option for generating the lists, there is a reuslt format called listwidget, that looks like this: http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Demo:Listwidget_paginated_list

Comment: I'm using wikia, so can't add extensions. I might be able to edit Common.js, and I might be able to turn my wiki semantic (wikia wikis aren't semantic by default, but you can ask them to add it). My thinking was: if category pages auto-paginate, that feature must exist somewhere inside MediaWiki's guts. Presumably, you could use it to paginate other things as well, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

No, the category pagination code is its own class and can't be used anywhere else.

There is a reusable class for pagination which is `TablePager`, used e.g. in `class ImageListPager extends TablePager`; but that's for extension developers.